# Two Rectangles logic error

Tags: java, arrays, string, graphics, logic

This program is suppose to take in the (x,y) coordinates and the width and height of two rectangles and displays both rectangles with a string saying they overlap, contain or don't overlap. I have the correct graphics. But my problem is in the logic of the string that is to be displayed. When the user inputs data for triangles that are not contained or overlap each other. It says they overlap. I need help fixing the logic of the code.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoRectangles extends Application {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        double width = 400;
        double height = 400;

        ArrayList<Rectangle> rectangles = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter (x, y) of center, width, and height or rec " + i + ": ");
            Rectangle temp = new Rectangle(input.nextDouble(), input.nextDouble(), input.nextDouble(),
                input.nextDouble());
            temp.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            temp.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

            rectangles.add(temp);
        }

        Rectangle rec1 = rectangles.get(0);
        Rectangle rec2 = rectangles.get(1);

        String s = "";

        if (!(rec1.contains(rec2.getWidth(), rec2.getHeight()) 
            || rec2.contains(rec1.getWidth(), rec1.getHeight()))) {
            s = "One rectangle is contained in another.";
        } else if (rec1.intersects(rec2.getX(), rec2.getY(), rec2.getWidth(), rec2.getHeight())
            || rec2.intersects(rec1.getX(), rec1.getY(), rec1.getWidth(), rec1.getHeight())) {
            s = "One rectangle overlaps another." ;
        } else {
            s = "The rectangles do not overlap.";
        }

        Text text = new Text(width * 0.1, height * 0.9, s);
        pane.getChildren().add(text);
        pane.getChildren().addAll(rectangles);
        primaryStage.setTitle("rectangles..");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, width, height));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your main problem is your "contains" check.  It only takes into consideration the width and height of the rectangles, not where they are located.  You could write a "contains" method like:

```
private static boolean contains(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2) {
    return r1.getX() <= r2.getX() && r1.getY() <= r2.getY()
            && r2.getX() + r2.getWidth() <= r1.getX() + r1.getWidth()
            && r2.getY() + r2.getHeight() <= r1.getY() + r1.getHeight();
}
```

then change your check to

```
    if (contains(rec1, rec2) || contains(rec2, rec1)) {
        s = "One rectangle is contained in another.";
    } else if (rec1.intersects(rec2.getX(), rec2.getY(), rec2.getWidth(), rec2.getHeight())) {
        s = "One rectangle overlaps another.";
    } else {
        s = "The rectangles do not overlap.";
    }
```

(you only need to check the intersection one way, since if rectangle A intersects B, then B also intersects A).

Answer (score 0):

Well, "contain" is easy enough:

```
boolean contain = rect1.contains(rect2) || rect2.contains(rect1);
```

After that, "overlap" is easy:

```
boolean overlap = ! contain && rect1.intersects(rect2);
```

Or, to get your string:

```
String s = (rect1.contains(rect2) || rect2.contains(rect1)
            ? "One rectangle is contained in another."
            : rect1.intersects(rect2)
              ? "One rectangle overlaps another."
              : "The rectangles do not overlap.");
```

Comment: Same exact output, I'm getting before